# How can I draw in canvas element with safari in iPad?

Tags: ipad, html

I´m trying to implement a canvas element to touch sign in Safari/iPad. I have done it for desktop browsers with mousedown mouseup and mousemove events. Which events I have to use for do the same in iPad? touchstart,touchend and touchmove?

here is my function

```
var pizarra_canvas
var pizarra_context

function init(){

    
    alert('2')
    pizarra_canvas = document.getElementById("pizarra");
    pizarra_context = pizarra_canvas.getContext("2d");
    pizarra_context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',empezarPintar,false);
    pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchend',terminarPintar,false);
alert('1')
}

function empezarPintar(e){
pizarra_context.beginPath();
pizarra_context.moveTo(e.clientX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.clientY-          pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
pizarra_canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',pintar,false)
}

function terminarPintar(e){
pizarra_canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove',pintar,false);
}

function pintar(e) {
pizarra_context.lineTo(e.clientX-pizarra_canvas.offsetLeft,e.clientY-    pizarra_canvas.offsetTop);
pizarra_context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Just found [jspaint.ml](http://jspaint.ml), including its [GitHub source code](https://github.com/1j01/jspaint). They draw on canvas, too. Maybe this can help as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to have a look at frameworks like http://www.kineticjs.com/ or http://paperjs.org/ which help a lot when dealing with canvas on a touch-screen.